# pkcs12: import password and PEM password

Tags: openssl

Why does `openssl` is requesting me two passwords in order to get `-info` of a `pkcs12` key?

It's requesting me `Import Password` and `PEM Pass Phrase`:

```
➜  front git:(master) ✗ openssl pkcs12 -info -in front.p12  
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 102400
...
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

What's each one for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with the options you have given OpenSSL will write the contents out to stdout.  If the PKCS12 file contains a private key it will ask you for a pass phrase to protect this private key, which you will need to enter twice.  You are therefore being asked once for the pass phrase to unlock the PKCS12 file and then twice for a new pass phrase for the exported private key.

If you only want to view the contents, add the `-noout` option:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in front.p12 -noout
```

OpenSSL will now only prompt you once for the PKCS12 unlock pass phrase.

More dangerously, you could replace the `-noout` with `-nodes` in which case the command will output the contents, including any private keys, without prompting you to encrypt the exported private keys.

Comment: Perfect, so there is nothing stopping me to unlock the PFX file (Enter Import Password), and reuse exactly the same password (Enter PEM pass phrase x2) on the private key !